# RelativeLayout alignment/positioning not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've had a look around, and not been able to find a fix to this problem. Yes it is something that has been asked before, but none of the solutions I've found has corrected my problem.

So basically, my problem is that I need two views to align to the right of their container, one next to the other. I can't stop them from overlapping however.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (screenWidth*0.30), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
newSpinner.setLayoutParams(param);
newSpinner.setId(-101);

param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (screenWidth*0.10), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
param.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, newSpinner.getId());
newButton.setLayoutParams(param);
```

The above code results in this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYOek.png

```
param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

While removing the above line results in this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJvYc.png

So what's the fix?

Comment: Upon further inspection, my code works fine in portrait mode, and it is only landscape where the button disappears/overlaps.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It appears that you rejected an edit by someone else. Note that you can always edit your own posts and approve suggested edits to your posts, even before reaching 2000 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same object 'param' for both spinner and button.
Try using like param1 and param2 for each in the first place.
Secondly try using

`param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);` for one item and 
`param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);` for the other to avoid overlapping.

Also try this solution. Create a relative layout with `param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);` and then add spinner and button in this relative layout, use `ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT` for one item and `LEFT_OF` for the other. Also make sure to use the  appropriate width of the items so that they should not overlap

Comment: Your first suggestion works fine for portrait, but the '?' button disappears in landscape mode.
The second suggestion is not helpful however, as I need both to be aligned to the right, as I have other items on the left.

Comment: i have updated the answer now try 1st and 3rd solution

Comment: No need to use different param objects by the way, since each time I reuse it, I redefine it as "new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams"

Answer (score 0):

Remove:
param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

From newButton.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have attempted this.